When $K(\zeta_p)\cong K(\zeta_{p^{n}-1})$?
I'm following Sutherland's note on Number theory (available here). I'm stuck with

Corollary $10.18$. Let $A$ be a complete DVR with fraction field $K$ and finite residue field of characteristic $p$. Suppose $K$ does not contain a primitive $p$-th root of unity. The extension $K(\zeta_m)/K$ is ramified if and only if $p|m$.

I have some problem in the "if " direction:
Suppose $p|m$, then $K(\zeta_p)\subset K(\zeta_m)$, and by a previous result we know that $K(\zeta_p)$ is unramified if and only if $K(\zeta_p)\cong K(\zeta_{p^{n}-1})$ where $n=[K(\zeta_p)/K]$. Then he concludes by saying that $K(\zeta_p)\cong K(\zeta_{p^{n}-1})$ if and only if $p|p^n -1$, and this is clearly impossible.
I don't understand why the above isomorphism is equivalent to saying that $p|p^n -1$. I see that if $\zeta_p\in K$ this could not be the case, but if $\zeta_p\notin K$ then I can only say that $\zeta_p=P(\zeta_{p^n-1})/Q(\zeta_{p^n-1})$, where $P,Q\in K[x]$, but I don't know how to conclude from here.
Any help? Thanks!

There is a typo is the proof of Cor. $10.18$ that you carried over to what you wrote: the only unramified extension of $K$ with degree $n$ is not $K(\zeta_{p^n-1})$, but is instead $K(\zeta_{q^n-1})$, where $q$ is the size of the residue field of $K$.
The corollary in your post is false: if $\zeta_p \not\in K$, then the extension $K(\zeta_p)/K$ need not be ramified: it can be unramified!
Example $1$. Let $K = \mathbf Q_3(\sqrt{-6})$. We have $K(\zeta_3) = K(\sqrt{-3})$, and since $\sqrt{-6}\in K$, we have $K(\sqrt{-3}) = K(\sqrt{2})$, so $K(\zeta_3)$ is quadratic unramified over $K$.
Such examples don’t occur when $p=2$ since $\zeta_2 = -1$ is in every field with characteristic zero.
Here is a way to build unramified extensions  $K(\zeta_p)/K$ with any chosen degree dividing $p-1$.
Theorem $1$. Let $p$ be prime and $f\mid (p-1)$. There is a totally ramified abelian extension $K/\mathbf Q_p$ of degree $p-1$ such that $K(\zeta_p)/K$ is unramified of degree $f$.
Proof. Let $\mathbf Q_{p^f}$ be the unramified  extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ with degree $f$. For example, when $p>2$, $\mathbf Q_{p^2} = \mathbf Q_p(\sqrt{u})$ where $u$ is a unit in $\mathbf Z_p$ such that $u\bmod p$ is not a square.
The field $L := \mathbf Q_{p^f}(\zeta_p)$ is totally ramified over $\mathbf Q_{p^f}$ with degree $p-1$ by the same proof used for $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_p)/\mathbf Q_p$. Thus
$$
e(L/\mathbf Q_p) = p-1, \ \ f(L/\mathbf Q_p) = f.
$$
By Galois theory, $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_p)\cap \mathbf Q_{p^f} = \mathbf Q_p$ and
$$
G := {\rm Gal}(L/\mathbf Q_p) \cong (\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times \times \mathbf Z/f\mathbf Z.
$$
The inertia group $I = I(L/\mathbf Q_p)$ has order $e(L/\mathbf Q_p) = p-1$, so $[L:L^I] = |I| = p-1$. Thus $[L^I:\mathbf Q_p] = f$. Since $L^I$ is the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ in $L$ and its degree over $\mathbf Q_p$ matches that of the known unramified extension $\mathbf Q_{p^f}$, we get $L^I = \mathbf Q_{p^f}$. Thus $I$ is the group fixing $\mathbf Q_{p^f}$, so $I = (\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times \times \{0\}$.
Since $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$ is cyclic and $f\mid (p-1)$, there is an automorphism $\sigma$ in ${\rm Gal}(\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_p)/\mathbf Q_p)$ with order $f$.
The Frobenius on $\mathbf Q_{p^f}$, which is the $p$-th power map on the $(p^f-1)$-th roots of unity, also has order $f$. These combine to a unique $g \in G$, so $g$ has order $f$. Set
$$
H = \langle g\rangle, \ \ K = L^H.
$$
Since $L/\mathbf Q_p$ is abelian, the subextension $K/\mathbf Q_p$ is abelian with
$[L:K] = [L:L^H] = |H| = f$, so
$$
[K:\mathbf Q_p] = \frac{[L:\mathbf Q_p]}{[L:K]} = \frac{(p-1)f}{f} = p-1.
$$
We’ll show $L = K(\zeta_p)$ by determining the automorphisms in $G \cong (\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times \times \mathbf Z/f\mathbf Z$ that fix $K(\zeta_p)$. Such automorphisms fix the elements of $K$, so they lie in $H$. Also they fix $\zeta_p$, and hence $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_p)$, so they lie in $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times \times \{0\}$. That subgroup has a trivial intersection with $H$, so the only element of $G$ fixing $K(\zeta_p)$ is the identity automorphism. Hence $L=K(\zeta_p)$.
Lastly, we show $L/K$ is unramified and $K/\mathbf Q_p$ is totally ramified.
Since $K$ is the field fixed by $H$,
$$
I(L/K) = I(L/\mathbf Q_p) \cap H = ((\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times \times \{0\}) \cap H,
$$
which again is trivial, so $L/K$ is unramified. Then
$$
e(K/\mathbf Q_p) = e(L/\mathbf Q_p) = p-1 = [K:\mathbf Q_p],
$$
so $K$ is totally ramified over $\mathbf Q_p$.
QED
Example $1$ at the start is the case $p=3$ and $f=2$, with $\mathbf Q_9 = \mathbf Q_3(\sqrt{2})$. I had posted it in a comment to a previous MSE question here. A more general set of examples with primitive $p$-power roots of unity for a $p$-power greater than $p$ is here.
Theorem $1$ is uninteresting when $p=2$, since $f = 1$. To have a result for all $p$ that is interesting when $p=2$, we can use $p$-power roots of unity of order greater than $p$, keeping in mind that ${\rm Gal}(\mathbf Q_2(\zeta_{2^n})/\mathbf Q_2) \cong (\mathbf Z/2^n\mathbf Z)^\times$ is not cyclic when $n\geq 3$: the maximal order of an element in this group is $2^{n-2}$ rather than its group size $2^{n-1}$. Here is the corresponding result, with a proof just like the one above, so the proof is left to the reader.
Theorem $2$. Let $p$ be prime, $n\geq 1$, and $f\mid p^{n-1}(p-1)$ when $p$ is odd or when $p=2$ and $n\leq 2$, and $f\mid 2^{n-2}$ when $p=2$ and $n\geq 3$. There is a totally ramified abelian extension $K/\mathbf Q_p$ of degree $p^{n-1}(p-1)$ such that $K(\zeta_{p^n})/K$ is unramified of degree $f$.
Example $2$. Using $p=2$, $n=2$, and $f=2$, we get $K=\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{3})$. Then $K(i) = K(\zeta_3)$ is a quadratic unramified extension of $K$.
Example $3$. Using $p=2$, $n=3$, and $f=2$, we have quadratic unramified extensions $K(\zeta_8)/K$ when $K$ is any of the fields $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{3})$, and $\mathbf Q_2(i,\sqrt{6})$. In all three cases,
$$
K(\zeta_8) = K(i,\sqrt{2}) = \mathbf Q_2(i,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) = \mathbf Q_2(\zeta_3,\zeta_8) = \mathbf Q_4(\zeta_8).
$$

Your claim is not correct: We only know that $K$ has no roots of unity of order $p$, but you use that $L$ has this property, too, which is not necessarily true.

@LukasHeger good point. I had a second argument using inertia groups in mind too, but had put that aside. I will reconsider it when I get some time.

@LukasHeger I completely changed my answer. Take a look now.

Interesting! I did not expect this. Though I think that it's still true that $K(\zeta_p)/K$ is ramified if $K$ is unramified over $\Bbb Q$. More generally if we have a quotient field $K$ of a DVR (no need to assume completeness) an unramified extension $L/K$ as well as a totally ramified extension $M/K$ , then $LM/L$ is totally ramified. This can be proved by playing around with ramification indices and field degrees.

I meant $Κ$ unramified over $\Bbb Q_p$ in the previous comment.

@LukasHeger  sure. And I updated the theorem in my answer so it gives unramified extensions of the form $K(\zeta_p)/K$ with any degree dividing $p-1$, not just quadratic unramified extensions of that form when $p>2$.
